# The Cron Service itself failed how do I find out why

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I have a remote raspberry pi that runs 24/7. It is running Debian bullseye.  Tasks that normally run daily failed to send some mail failed and I was told about it by the normal recipients.  When I went and looked (`sudo systemctl status cron.service`) `cron` had failed at 10:04 am on last Sunday (2023-12-17), but with no indication why.

I restarted it again and everything carried on again as normal.

I tried to find out what had happened and ran `sudo journalctl -t CRON --since "2023-12-17"` and it ran and produced entries up until 10:04 on Sunday then nothing until I restarted it today and it resumed working and then it showed those entries.

Is there somewhere else I can look so I can get some more clues as to why it terminated?

In case its relevant (I can't see why) the day before I had made a new release and re-orginised these cron jobs. It appears I'd made a mistake and a number of the cron jobs never terminated. So mid afternoon on the Saturday the whole machine disappeared (in the sense I could no longer ssh into it). I am postulating that it filled up memory and then swap space until the kernel had to kill some things, because after 7 hours the machine appeared again (ie an attempt to ssh into it succeeded).  I noticed that there will some hung cron jobs and killed them off and then went back and fixed all the cron jobs so that they terminated properly. `cron` was clearly running successfully after that incident.

Comment: What do you find in the _unfiltered_ system log at around that time?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your syslog file which should be here:
`/var/log/syslog`

Unlikely but you might also find some clues in the cron log:
`/var/log/cron`

Comment: definitely more stuff in there than journalctl returned, but nothing definititve